# Leitura de input de matriz no python

Tags: python, matriz

Estou querendo saber como criar uma matriz no python, mas o input seria a matriz inteira.
eu tentei fazer:

```
matrix=[]
for r in range(5):
    row=[]
    for c in range(5):
        row.append(input().split())
    matrix.append(row)
```

Mas continua da erro e nao consigo ler o input abaixo:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de ler ela inteira sem usar numpy e panda??

Answer (score 1):

Como você já está informando a linha inteira em um mesmo `input`, você não precisará de dois laços de repetidos, apenas um, executando o número de vezes referente à quantidade de linhas da matriz:

```
matrix=[]
for r in range(5):
    matrix.append(input().split())
```

Comment: funcionou,muito obrigado